# mysql_query select from multiple columns with OR

Tags: php, mysql

I have:

`$sql = mysql_query("select * from articles where articletitle OR articledescription OR articletags like '%$term%'");`

and it returns no results.

Am I using OR incorrectly here?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys. I've up voted all of you, will give the answer to Dacto as he has the least reputation at the moment...if that's fair?

Comment: Good luck and have fun with programming! Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add LIKE to all three clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE (articletitle LIKE '%$term%') OR (articledescription LIKE '%$term%') OR (articletags LIKE '%$term%');
```

Comment: You don't need the parens since you are ORing each item

Comment: Yeah I know, but it helps separate what someone who is learning is looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.. you need to use the like '...' everytime

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from articles where articletitle like '%$term%' OR 
articledescription like '%$term%' OR articletags like '%$term%'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. :-) You're using it incorrectly.

```
select * from articles where (articletitle like '%$term%') 
OR (articledescription like '%$term%') OR (articletags like '%$term%')
```

Answer (score 0):

On a side comment, what would happen if $term is exactly (minus double quotes) "';DELETE FROM articles;-- "? (Add a closing paren after the single quote if your original query had such.) I recommend you rely on some sprintf-like facility (in PHP it often means you'll need prepared statements) rather than the deprecated misfeature known as magic quotes.